# Table users doesnt exist laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, web-hosting

I have deploy my laravel project but i dont know my users table is doesnt exist

**user model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
use HasFactory, Notifiable;

public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
public function ketua(){
    return $this->hesOne(Team::class);
}
public function requestjoin(){
    return $this->hasMany(Requestjoin::class);
}

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'role',
    'name',
    'email',
    'kontak',
    'password',
    'npm',
    'program_studi',
    'fakultas'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];}
```

**Controller store**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use stdClass;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use App\Http\Requests\RegistrationRequest;
use App\Models\Mhsw;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    public function store(RegistrationRequest $request)
    {
        $attributes = $request->all();

        $attributes['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
        
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $attributes['name'];
        $user->email = $attributes['email'];
        $user->kontak = $attributes['kontak'];
        $user->npm = $attributes['npm'];
        $user->program_studi = $attributes['program_studi'];
        $user->fakultas = $attributes['fakultas'];
        $user->password = $attributes['password'];
        $user->save();
        


        Alert::success('Berhasil daftar', 'Silahkan login');

        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

**store method**

```
 public function store(RegistrationRequest $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->all();

    $attributes['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
    
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $attributes['name'];
    $user->email = $attributes['email'];
    $user->kontak = $attributes['kontak'];
    $user->npm = $attributes['npm'];
    $user->program_studi = $attributes['program_studi'];
    $user->fakultas = $attributes['fakultas'];
    $user->password = $attributes['password'];
    $user->save();
    


    Alert::success('Berhasil daftar', 'Silahkan login');

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

**User migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('team_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('role')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('kontak')->unique();
        $table->string('npm')->unique();
        $table->string('program_studi');
        $table->string('fakultas');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**env db**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pkme1826_pkmtest
```

**error**

[image]

**phpmyadmin**

```
public function store(RegistrationRequest $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->all();

    $attributes['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $attributes['nama'];
    $user->email = $attributes['email'];
    $user->kontak = $attributes['kontak'];
    $user->npm = $attributes['npm'];
    $user->program_studi = $attributes['program_studi'];
    $user->fakultas = $attributes['fakultas'];
    $user->password = $attributes['password'];

    User::create($attributes);
    


    Alert::success('Berhasil daftar', 'Silahkan login');

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

im trying to register new user and showing that error, I don't know where is the error code, i have migrate the database with routing and call artisan but keep showing error

Comment: It's odd that the code is looking for table `Users` instead of `users` this may be problematic because the table is usually stored as a file so the name may or may not be case sensitive depending on the underlying file system

Comment: Did you change the default table for the Model to 'Users' normally Laravel uses lowercase table names.

Comment: `php artisan migrate` sudah?

Comment: @GertB. i didnt change anything from model users

Comment: @WahyuKristianto i have edited my question

Comment: @WahyuKristianto i have found my error code that is from my request validation.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Registrationrequest with rule that contain

```
unique:Users
```

That should

```
unique:users
```